# Browser compatibility issue with firefox 3.6.10

Tags: javascript, html, django, firefox, cross-browser

I am developing an application in `django`,in which a section is for photo file and voice file upload.My problem is both bottons are not working in `firefox 3.6.10` version,it is working in `firefox 21`.If i click the choose button,in `firefox 3.6.10`,click is not happening,so user is not able to upload photos or voice files.

see my html code for choose file button,

```
<button id="choose" type="button" class="button_style" value="Choose_File" onclick="$('#file').click()">Choose File</button>
```

Need solution.

Comment: Any reason for not using an `<input type="file" />` directly?

Comment: Triggering file dialogs on `click` is not reliable in all browsers. A typical workaround is to trigger the click on the label linked to the input, but again this will only work on some browsers (IE for example), so you'd have to do this selectively.

Comment: Same issue is happening in IE8 also,how to make it work in all browser.

Comment: Can i get any answer for this question please.

Answer (score 0):

for safety reasons, at that time that was firefox 3.x version was impossible to establish some properties to the DOM of an input file type. Over time this changed, only supports HTML5 browsers can access the content type of the input file including the onclick event.